# OCaml Parsing String into String*Int list

Tags: parsing, ocaml, lexer

```
type unit_t = (string * int) list
```

How would I go about creating an expression to parse a string into this form? Do I need to implement code in a `parser.mly` format in order to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no real way to give a detailed answer, since you don't say how the original string is supposed to correspond to your list of pairs.

Based just on the simplicity of your output type, I'd say you could do this without invoking the full machinery of ocamlyacc. I.e., I doubt you need a `parser.mly` file. You could use ocamllex, or you could just apply some regular expressions from the `Str` module. It depends on what your parsing actually needs to do.

Here's one possibility that uses regular expressions from `Str`:

```
let p s =
    let fs = Str.full_split (Str.regexp "[0-9]+") s in
    let rec go = function
    | [] -> []
    | Str.Text s :: Str.Delim i :: rest -> (s, int_of_string i) :: go rest
    | Str.Text s :: rest -> (s, 0) :: go rest
    | Str.Delim i :: rest -> ("", int_of_string i) :: go rest
    in
    go fs
```

You can run it like this:

```
# #load "str.cma";;
# #use "p.ml";;
val p : string -> (string * int) list = <fun>
# p "123abc456def";;
- : (string * int) list = [("", 123); ("abc", 456); ("def", 0)]
# p "ghi789jkl100";;
- : (string * int) list = [("ghi", 789); ("jkl", 100)]
```